# C# AWS S3 Uploads Corrupted File

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

C# newbie.

I'm trying to write some code which will copy S3 bucket content from one AWS account and place them in another S3 account using AWS SDK.

My issue is that while the filenames appear in the destination bucket, the content/file seem to be corrupted.
As a test I got it copy and move an image.
The source image is 193KB but the file in the destination bucket is 339 KBs which seem a bit.

Below is my code.
Starts with the `ListAndCopyObjects` method as entry point.
Client, destinationClient is already defined in another part of the code.
Any help is greatly appreciated.
I've been banging my head on this for days now.

```
public static async Task ListAndCopyObjects(string bucketName, string folderName, AmazonS3Client client)
        {
            // Read all bucket files
            Console.WriteLine("Listing Objects");
            var listObjects = client.Paginators.ListObjectsV2(new ListObjectsV2Request()
            {
                BucketName = bucketName,
                Prefix = folderName,
                StartAfter = folderName
            });
            
            Console.WriteLine("Loop through Files");
            
            await foreach (var response in listObjects.Responses)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"HttpStatusCode: {response.HttpStatusCode}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Number of Keys: {response.KeyCount}");
                foreach (var entry in response.S3Objects)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Key = {entry.Key} Size = {entry.Size}");
                    //Download file data
                    NameValueCollection fileContent = await DownloadObject(client, bucketName, entry.Key);
                    
                    Console.WriteLine(fileContent);
                    //Upload file
                    await UploadObject(destinationClient, Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DESTINATION_BUCKET"),
                        entry.Key, fileContent);
                }
            }
        }

        private static async Task<bool> UploadObject(AmazonS3Client client, string bucketName, string objectName, 
            NameValueCollection fileContents)
        {
            var request = new PutObjectRequest
            {
                BucketName = bucketName,
                Key = objectName,
                ContentBody = fileContents["content"],
                ContentType = fileContents["contentType"]
            };

            var response = await client.PutObjectAsync(request);
            if (response.HttpStatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Successfully uploaded {objectName} to {bucketName}.");
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Could not upload {objectName} to {bucketName}.");
                return false;
            }
        }
        
        private static async Task<NameValueCollection> DownloadObject(AmazonS3Client client, string bucketName, string objectName)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Downloading File");
            NameValueCollection fileData = new NameValueCollection();
            try
            {
                GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest
                {
                    BucketName = bucketName,
                    Key = objectName
                };
                using (GetObjectResponse response = await client.GetObjectAsync(request))
                using (Stream responseStream = response.ResponseStream)
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                {
                    string title = response.Metadata["x-amz-meta-title"];
                    string contentType = response.Headers["Content-Type"];
                    Console.WriteLine("Object metadata, Title: {0}", title);
                    Console.WriteLine("Content type: {0}", contentType);

                    fileData["contentType"] = contentType;
                    fileData["content"] = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    
                    return fileData;
                }
            }
            catch (AmazonS3Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error encountered ***. Message:'{0}' when writing an object", e.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unknown encountered on server. Message:'{0}' when writing an object", e.Message);
            }

            return fileData;
        }
```

Comment: Um, are the files you're reading actually _text_?

Comment: Some are text, some are images @ProgrammingLlama

Comment: Why are you treating all files as text then? With UTF8 (which is the default encoding that `StreamReader` will use), you're going to get corruptions if the bytes it reads don't represent UTF8-encoded text.

Comment: That's probably what I'm missing. Appreciate if you can point me in the right direction.

Comment: In short: you want to replicate the files byte-for-byte, so you'll need to read the files into a `byte[]` or `MemoryStream`, not a `string`.

Comment: Thank you. Any chance I could trouble to see how this would look like? Totally C# newbie that's been thrown in to the deepend.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I've added an answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Probable cause for corruption

It seems likely that your issue comes from treating any file as UTF8-encoded text. Text encoding generally expects a specific arrangement of binary data, and trying to convert any binary data to text will "work" but oftentimes (depending on the encoding) will result in changed (corrupted) data when written back to binary.

## Solution

Since you're new, I've tried to make as few changes as possible to your code to make it work, but please review my suggested improvements.

Since you want to transfer any kind of data, you will probably want to look at using something that can hold binary data instead. Since `PutObjectRequest` takes a `Stream`, it seems like a `MemoryStream` could be a good option here. I've updated your `DownloadObject` method to download the data into a `MemoryStream` and save that in your `NameValueCollection`, which I've had to change to a `Dictionary<string, object>`:

```cs
private static async Task<Dictionary<string, object>> DownloadObject(AmazonS3Client client, string bucketName, string objectName)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Downloading File");
    Dictionary<string, object> fileData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    try
    {
        GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest
        {
            BucketName = bucketName,
            Key = objectName
        };

        var contentStream = new MemoryStream();
        using (GetObjectResponse response = await client.GetObjectAsync(request))
        using (Stream responseStream = response.ResponseStream)
        {
            string title = response.Metadata["x-amz-meta-title"];
            string contentType = response.Headers["Content-Type"];
            Console.WriteLine("Object metadata, Title: {0}", title);
            Console.WriteLine("Content type: {0}", contentType);


            await responseStream.CopyToAsync(contentStream);
            contentStream.Position = 0;

            fileData["contentType"] = contentType;
            fileData["content"] = contentStream;
        }

        return fileData;
    }
    catch (AmazonS3Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error encountered ***. Message:'{0}' when writing an object", e.Message);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Unknown encountered on server. Message:'{0}' when writing an object", e.Message);
    }

    return fileData;
}
```

Then I've updated your `UploadObject` method to use the stream with `PutObjectRequest`'s `InputStream` method:

```cs
private static async Task<bool> UploadObject(AmazonS3Client client, string bucketName, string objectName,
    Dictionary<string, object> fileContents)
{
    var request = new PutObjectRequest
    {
        BucketName = bucketName,
        Key = objectName,
        InputStream = (Stream)fileContents["content"],
        ContentType = (string)fileContents["contentType"]
    };

    var response = await client.PutObjectAsync(request);
    if (response.HttpStatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Successfully uploaded {objectName} to {bucketName}.");
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Could not upload {objectName} to {bucketName}.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

You'll need to also change the line in your Copy method to either `Dictionary<string, object>` or `var`:

```cs
var fileContent = await DownloadObject(client, bucketName, entry.Key);
```

## Suggested improvements

The biggest problem I feel this code has is that, while each piece of code is separated nicely, you're ultimately having to read entire files into memory. If the files are small, that won't be too bad, but if the files are big, it can take up a lot of RAM.

Possible solutions:

1. Use `CopyObjectRequest` and the `CopyObjectAsync` method instead. The issue here is that this limits you to copying 5GB files.
2. Open the read stream from the existing file, and pass that directly to `InputStream`, which ought to just stream the file through your server rather than loading the entire file into memory at once. Remember to still put it in a  `using` to dispose of it correctly on failure, though you'll need to do this in a place where it only gets disposed after upload is completed/failed.
3. Not relevant but, if you were copying from another service such as Google Storage, you could read parts of the file and upload them using S3's Multipart uploads functionality. Once all the parts are uploaded, you mark it as completed so that it becomes a full file.

Another thing is that using a `NameValueCollection` or even `Dictionary<string, object>` introduces the possibility for mistakes. What if you misspelled `"content"` as `"cntent"` for example? It would cause a runtime exception. It's probably better to build a small class to house your information. Assuming your version of the C# language is >= 8.0, you can also use records for this (e.g. `private record FileData(string contentType, Stream dataStream);`) and then use that like a regular class.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much for the detailed explanation and suggested improvements. Luckily the file sizes are small but will definitely keep these in mind. Appreciate your help on this one.